# time.clock() several times in Python?

Tags: python, time, clock

Using Python 2.7.5 on Windows 7, I have a problem.

I am writing a program that's supposed to calculate the time it takes to calculate a few mathematical algorithms.
I use `start=time.clock()` and `elapsed=time.clock()-start`. That works, but when i try to do `start=time.clock()` a second time it does not work. I get this message:

```
start=time.time()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time'
```

I obviously cant use `time.clock()` several times, but what can i use instead?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your code somewhere has `time = <some calculated value>` replacing the name "time" from pointing to the correct module to a float object.

Comment: No thats not the problem. The code looks exactly the same as the one that works. I "copy-pasted" it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, I can call time.clock() as many time as I want, and the error you get is telling you that your "time" object is a float

Comment: I deleted everything and wrote the program again, its so short and simple. Now it works. I still have no idea what was wrong since I even use the same names for the variables.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use [`time.clock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock):

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

Instead use [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time):

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.
>   Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point
>   number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1
>   second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it
>   can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has
>   been set back between the two calls.

To put the difference into easier terms: The first time you call `time.clock()` it will start a timer, every subsequent call to `time.clock()` will yield the time since the first call. Whereas using `time.time()` will always give you the time since the epoch.

To clarify, `time.clock()` is a relative time measurement method, relative to when you first start timing using the `time.clock()` method, whereas when using `time.time()` you are getting the seconds since the epoch each time.

In both methods you can deduce the difference between them quite easily, but using `time.clock()` can have unforeseen consequences when more complex time measurements are needed, like multiple threads, or different functions that have to communicate with each other - if they are all timing themselves relative to themselves, it is hard to keep things constant.

Comment: time.time() is NOT a replacement for time.clock. time.time() provides system time so if for example NTP server changed the time between the start and end, you may get wrong results (including negative results)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

I found that I named a variable 'time' which is the **same name** that the time module.

So it answers you that your variable time has no attribute time because your variable overwrites your module time.

**Check your variable names or change the module name !**

Comment: Thank you! This kind of error happened to me already multiple times (though another operator or method or whatsoever is involved)..  it is so frustrating..  :D

Answer (score 0):

You could to

```
start1 = time.clock()

Calculation

print "Runtime: " + str(time.clock() - start1)

start2 = time.clock()

Calculation

print "Runtime: " + str(time.clock() - start2)
```